# Test that program starts without errors - redefine input() to sys.exit(0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

I have some python program which expects user input, let's call it myprogram.py, but would like an automated test that checks that the program gets to the first input() call. Any ideas how to do this, without changing the source code of the program itself?

I thought the easiest way would be to redefine the input() built in, if at all possible. Something along the lines of:

```
import sys
def input():
    sys.exit(0)
run("./src/myprogram.py")
```

(Note that I need the redefined input() function to work in imported modules as well).

Comment: Have you thought about logging?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I know the pseudo code above doesn't work. Just trying to convey my intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more generally I found this from a mailing list:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-April/573829.html

Solved it using builtins global - leaving the solution here for others searching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Test that program starts"""

import path_fix # Not important - adds src package to path
import sys

global __builtins__
def input():
    sys.exit(0)

__builtins__.input = input

from src import myprogram

myprogram.main()
```

(Assumes myprogram has a callable main function, mine has).

**Edit:** Or in py.test:

```
import sys
import builtins

def test_starts():
    def input():
        sys.exit(0)

    builtins.input = input

    from src import myprogram
    try:
        myprogram.main()
        raise Exception
    except SystemExit as se:
        if se.code != 0:
            raise Exception
```

Comment: Your `myprogram` module wouldn't necessarily need to contain a `main` function. Just importing a module will run all the top-level code in it, so you could just move its `import` to inside the `try` block (and leave the `myprogram.main()` statement part out). Also, you don't need the `global __builtins__` in the first snippet (besides, it's already a global, since it's a built-in).

Answer (score 0):

You can change that builtin (as well as most others) for the Python program currently executing with something along these lines:

```
import builtins
import sys

def input():
    sys.exit(0)

builtins.input = input

...rest of program...
```

and it will affect code that's executed *within* that program from that point onwards, including any other modules that are subsequently imported. However it **won't** affect other scripts executed externally as separate processes (assuming you meant `subprocess.run()` when you wrote `run` in your question).

Comment: Nice. builtins module seems cleaner than `__builtins__`

Comment: @olehermanse: They're not necessarily the same thing. From the docs: "...most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute".